# Attempting to convert from GML to GeoJSON produces garbage

Tags: ogr2ogr

The file seems to convert without error, however when I attempt to display it on anything or any map, the coordinates are always rendered as a straight line across the top of the projection. I am not certain if the problem is my map or the conversion suite.

The data I am trying to convert is from StatsCan, which can be found here:

http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-i-eng.cfm?year=15

I'm starting to think they did something screwy with the format - this doesn't work (either from gml or shp), but I can follow the same process with other files and get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried opening the GML in another GIS package (e.g. QGIS) to check if it's valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works perfectly well when converting the GML to GeoJSON with [`ogr2ogr`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) (which can also be used from inside QGIS).

`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON geojson_test.geojson lcsd000a15g_e.gml`

Displays correctly and overlaps with the original GML file:

[image]